# How to generate bit-shift equations?

Tags: c#, math, bit-manipulation, equations

<strike>Preferably for this to be done in C#.</strike>

Supposedly, I have an integer of **1024**.
I will be able to generate these equations:

```
4096  >> 2 = 1024  
65536 >> 6 = 1024
64    << 4 = 1024
```

and so on...

Any clues or tips or guides or ideas?

**Edit**: Ok, in simple terms, what I want is, for example...Hey, I'm giving you an integer of 1024, now give me a list of possible bit-shift equations that will always return the value of 1024.

Ok, scratch that. It seems my question wasn't very concise and clear. I'll try again.
What I want, is to **generate** a list of possible bit-shift equations based on a numerical value. For example, if I have a value of 1024, how would I generate a list of possible equations that would always return the value of 1024?

**Sample Equations:**

```
4096  >> 2 = 1024  
65536 >> 6 = 1024  
64    << 4 = 1024
```

In a similar way, if I asked you to give me some additional equations that would give me 5, you would response:

```
3  + 2 = 5  
10 - 5 = 5  
4  + 1 = 5
```

Am I still too vague? I apologize for that.

Comment: Are you looking for the `<<` and `>>` operators?

Comment: So, what is the actual question? "any clues?" is awfully vague..

Comment: Homework? Would using `>>` and `<<` be considered cheating?

Comment: :Facepalm: It's meant to be << and >>, not < and >. My bad...

Comment: Rewrote the question, hopefully I have made myself clear.

Answer (score 0):

You may reverse each equation and thus "generate" possible equations:

```
1024 >> 4 == 64
```

and therefore

```
64 << 4 == 1024
```

Thus generate all right/left shifts of 1024 without loosing bits due to overflow or underflow of your variable and then invert the corresponding equation.

Answer (score 0):

Just add an extra '>' or '<':

```
uint value1= 4096 >> 2;
uint value2 = 65536 >> 6;
uint value3 = 64 << 4;
```

http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/CSharpShiftOperators.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking *why* these relationships exist? Shifting bits left by 1 bit is equivalent to multiplying by 2. So `512 << 1 = 512 * 2 = 1024`. Shifting right by 1 is dividing by 2. Shifting by 2 is multiplying/dividing by 4, by n is 2^n. So `1 << 10 = 1 * 2^10 = 1024`. To see why, write the number out in binary: let's take 7 as an example:

```
7 -> 0000 0111b
7 << 1 -> 0000 1110b = 14
7 << 3 -> 0011 1000b = 56
```

If you already knew all this, I apologize, but you might want to make the question less vague.